# Call a function from module.exports and give value to its parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, listener

I am building NodeJS code that listens to requests from specific ports and returns a response to it, here is the main code:

```
module.exports = function (port) {
    var fs            = require("fs");
    var path          = require("path");
    var express       = require('express');
    var vhost         = require('vhost');
    var https         = require('https');
    var http          = require('http');
    var bodyParser    = require("body-parser");
    
    var normalizedPath = require("path").join(__dirname, "../BlazeData/ssl/");
    
    var options = {
        key: fs.readFileSync(normalizedPath + 'spring14.key'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(normalizedPath + 'spring14.cert'),
    };

    var app = express();
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    var normalizedPath = path.join(__dirname, "../WebServices");
    fs.readdirSync(normalizedPath).forEach(function(file) {
        if (file.indexOf('.js') != -1) {
            var url = file.substring(0, file.length - 3);
            app.use(vhost(url, require(normalizedPath+"/"+file).app));
            
            console.log( 'Registered Service -> %s:%d', url, port );
        }
    });
    
    if (port == 80) {
        var server = http.createServer(app).listen(port, function(){
            console.log("Create HTTP WebServices");
            console.log( 'Express server listening on port %d in %s mode', port, app.settings.env );
        });
    }
    
    if (port == 443) {
        var server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, function(){
            console.log("Create HTTPS WebServices");
            console.log( 'Express server listening on port %d in %s mode', port, app.settings.env );
        });
    }
    
}
```

I have another JS file that is used to run the script above, I use
`var https1 = require('./clientAuthServer')` to initiate the code from above where clientAuthServer.js is the filename of the main code, however it just skips everything from that file.

How would I call `module.exports = function (port)` from a separate file and give a value to the parameter "port" which the function is using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you require your module it returns a function (the function exported by the module). The function is being assigned to the variable `https1`, so you simply need to call that function because right now it's just being stored.

The simplest way would be for your require statement to look something like this:

```
const https1 = require("./clientAuthServer")(parameter);
```

Where `parameter` is just whatever value you want to pass to the function.

Comment: IMO it'd be clearer to import the function at the top of the file and call it in the mainline code. It makes the code longer, but makes what's happening much more clear.

Comment: @DaveNewton That could work too. It looks like OP is trying to start a server, so it's likely they need the function to execute when the module is required which is why I suggested invoking the function like that. There are different ways to do this though.